# Is "He told me he will come here." redundant?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I feel the sentence, *"He told me he will come here."* is redundant and bit wired because "he" appears twice.

I'm writing the sentence in a message to my close friend. So, I can say it with casual manner.

I guess *"He told me to come here."* is wrong sentence. How do I rewrite that sentence to be more simple and casual?

Comment: *He told me to come here* is a good sentence, but it means something different from the first sentence. And it would be hard to write the first sentence without saying *he* twice. Even *I spoke to him; he's on his way* is not considered redundant, despite *he* and *him* being so close together.  In English we can't omit pronouns as often as you can in other languages.

Comment: But if you say *There's a cat in the yard. The cat is climbing a tree* now that doesn't sound so good, as you don't have to say  *the cat* the second time (the brain has already registered that what is in the yard is *a cat*); here we'd almost always use a pronoun instead of repeating *cat*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sentence isn't wrong at all. Moreover, it isn't really very redundant. The "he" part may sound redundant to you as a non-English speaker, but it is really quite natural.

If you want something more colloquial that is shorter, you could say

> He said he'd come here.

But what you have is entirely fine (in terms of redundancy).

Comment: Shouldn't it be: He said he would come here?

Comment: @Vahid "he'd" is a contraction for "he would", so yes, you're right - those are the same. Colloquially, people use the contraction.

Answer (score 2):

When you say a sentence is [redundant](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/50-redundant-phrases-to-avoid/), it means it has unnecessary words or phrases. In other words, those unnecessary words or phrases could be omitted, which will not change its meaning.

For example, when you say "I met her at 5 p.m. in the afternoon," you would notice that either "p.m." or "in the afternoon" is redundant as both basically mean the same thing.

However, in your example, the personal pronoun **he** has an important role in the sentence which can't be omitted. The first *he* is the speaker of the sentence and the second is the performer of the action "coming". If you change or elide either of them, the sentence will not have the same meaning which proves that repeating *he* twice is not redundant.

A side note: You should use an indefinite article before "stupid" and "wrong". Also, you have to use "weird" in place of "wired" and "in" should be used before manner and more idiomatic expression will be "in a casual manner", not "with casual manner".

Answer (score 1):

When writing a sentence like this you could replace the first He with the proper name.

What I mean:
Original - "He told me he will come here"
Modification - "Bob told me he will come here"

Based on the sentence I expect this is a brief statement in a text or instant message type format.  While the modification does not change the sentence's structure, it does identify the subject.  The identification does two things: establishes who "he" is, and removes the feeling of redundancy.